# Compare Json in Hierachy to Set Vars

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, comparison

I need to set three category meta vars on a product page from json IDs. Each product page can have any number of products on the page, and each product can have values for each of those categories.

If Product 1 has values, we use those. However, if Product 1 has a zero ('None' category) or it is undefined, it needs to fall through to the next product and so on until a category value is found, or it gets set to 'None' if it reaches the end of the product comparison.

JSON

```
_jsonmeta = [
    { "Product": 1, "c1": 0, "c2": 1111, "c3": undefined },
    { "Product": 2, "c1": 2222, "c2": 2222, "c3": undefined }];
    //should set category1=2222, category2 = 1111, category3 = 0 ('None')
```

Then I set each category by passing in the item and the index

```
function compareJson(json) {
        $.each(json, function (i, item) {
            //update if applicable
            category1 = checkForNullOrZero(item.c1, i);

            category2 = checkForNullOrZero(item.c2, i);

            category3 = checkForNullOrZero(item.c3, i);
        });
```

Then I need a way to sort, filter, or compare the current value against all other products' respective category.

```
function checkForNullOrZero(categoryidarg, indexarg) {
        if (categoryidarg == null || typeof categoryidarg === 'undefined') {
            //ignore it if undefined
            console.log('Ignore: ' + categoryidarg);
        }
        else if (categoryidarg == 0) {
            //check the others because this category is 'None'
            console.log('Fall through to next: ' + _jsonmeta[indexarg]);
        }
        else {
            //check the hierarchy to see if this Area trumps the others
            console.log('Compare: ' + categoryidarg + ' vs ' + _jsonmeta[indexarg]);
        }

       //need to return category here
    }
    }
```

Here is a full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/6mwpff7p/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do it that way, from the `checkForNullOrZero` function you either have to return (1) the value of current category or (2) the value of the current product of the category.

I think it might be easier to define categories as an array:

```
var categories = [undefined,undefined,undefined];
```

and then change the `compareJson` function as so:

```
function compareJson(json) {
    $.each(json, function (i, item) {
        //update if applicable
        categories[0] = checkForNullOrZero(item.c1, 0);

        categories[1] = checkForNullOrZero(item.c2, 1);

        categories[2] = checkForNullOrZero(item.c3, 2);
    });
}
```

and then from the `checkForNullOrZero` function, you have access to `categories[indexarg]`, which is the original value you should return if the new value doesn't overwrite it.

A working fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6mwpff7p/5/

A problem with this solution is that is checks every product, even if all categories are already set. A better solution might be to use a for loop. Fiddle with this method is: http://jsfiddle.net/6mwpff7p/6/

Comment: Great, the second method is better. I'll go with that, thanks.